# Should we be using SSH or psexec? What are the benefits of each?

Tags: windows, ssh, psexec

Our development operations team currently builds source and deploys that source to target boxes - the typical setup. Currently we use psexec to issue commands to remote hosts (i.e., shut down the environments, transfer the new code, boot back up the environments, etc.)

Would we be better off using SSH for this stuff? Would it be more reliable / user friendly? Could someone help me understand any pros / cons to each?

Comment: It would depend who you ask. Everyone has their own preference. I personally use SSH for the simplicity of setup, but others may disagree. What you might find "user friendly" I might not and vice verse. Not sure what you mean by "reliable".

Answer (score 3):

Considering the fact that Windows doesn't come with SSH out of the box you will have to set it up on all your current boxes you deploy to.

Of course you can setup an install script to automate this with a shell script via psexec :)

It really depends on your use case.

How important is security?

SSH was designed as a replacement for telnet. It gives you a shell on the remote machine as telnet does but all the data is sent through a secure tunnel so if anyone is sniffing packets all the data will be encrypted.

Overall SSH is way more versatile. You can setup TCP forwarding so that other applications can use your SSH Tunnel to communicate. An example of this would be VNC. Normally the remote frame buffer (your screen data) is sent unencrypted over your network. You can easily connect to the remote machine via SSH and then use the SSH Tunnel to send the screen data in a secure manner.

PSEXEC is a great tool for what you describe above. It requires no extra setup (baked into windows).

PSEXEC uses RPC (Remote Procedure Calls) to communicate. I believe that once the "communication channel" is established then the data is encrypted though I am not entirely sure of the methods used (SSH can be configured in a number of ways).

However if you need to provide any user credentials then it will send across the network `in PLAIN TEXT`. I believe this may be written in the output of the `psexec /?` command. Though I am not in front of a windows box at the moment to verify.

See this [LINK](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) for options, it has a note on this before the examples section.

So again it really depends on what you need to do. As far as stability. I haven't really ever had any stability issues with PSEXEC. I wouldn't say that stability would be a reason to consider SSH over PSEXEC unless your having problems using PSEXEC.

PSEXEC is not as configurable as SSH. Unless you running into PSEXEC's limitations you may need to consider SSH. If you are simply copying new code and rebooting remote machines and not passing credentials through PSEXEC (i.e. running the commands through your current username on the remote) then why not keep doing that?

As a matter of fact, if you just need to do copying and restarting why not just use some `cmd.exe` commands like `copy`/`xcopy`/`shutdown` (if its on your LAN or you have other route to it like through VPN) instead of PSEXEC?